# Global nuget config out of sync

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm trying to add a new source to nuget config using `nuget sources add -name`
I'm getting the following error

```
The name specified has already been added to the list of available package sources. Provide a unique name.
```

Although my global nuget.config contains just one source (with different name and source):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

When I run `nuget sources list` , I get list of 3 sources , (global config contains single source).
How is it possible that nuget.config file and `nuget sources list` give different output?
Thanks!

Edited:
MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: there are three locations where you could check to start:  somewhere in the path where you ran the command, perhaps you have an nuget.config file somewhere higher in the tree.  there could be an nuget.config in your user folder and one in your  appdata\roaming\nuget folder

Comment: I edited the question :MacOS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: I tried to run "nuget sources list" from the same folder of the Nuget.config , the information is still wront